# Android nestedScrollview And ViewPager not working together

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I am developing an app which has a viewPager and it should scroll

[image]

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_nestedscrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFA0"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

but viewPager is not visible if i use above code

Comment: It is not possible you can set fix size of view pager..

Comment: Same problem I face there are two solutions for this colapsingLayout or otherwise fix the viewpager height

Answer (score 5):

You are doing it wrong. This is the correct way:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFA0"/>
```

Fragment layout parent view should be

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_nestedscrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks but I have also done that but then my viewPager was not working.

Comment: i have solved it by giving viewPager a Fixed Height.but is there any other solution.

Comment: @Avinash Are you using NestedScrollView inside a CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: @ZayidMohammed no I am using it in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 4):

I am too late to answer this but I face the same problem.

**First Solution**
To solve this problem is to  give fix height to viewpager.

**Second Solution**
Use CollapsingToolbarLayout and  redesign layout according to CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: fix height to viewpager helped, thank you!